# Counting number of quadruples of integers

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

> I saw this question today where we need to count the number of
>   quadruples of integers 
>   `(X1, X2, X3, X4)`, such that Li ≤ Xi ≤ Ri for i
>   = 1, 2, 3, 4 and X1 ≠ X2, X2 ≠ X3, X3 ≠ X4, X4 ≠ X1.

```
    input:
     Li Ri
     1  4 
     1  3 
     1  2 
     4  4

output:
8

1 2 1 4
1 3 1 4
1 3 2 4
2 1 2 4
2 3 1 4
2 3 2 4
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 4
```

My initial thoughts were using

> Principle of Inclusion Exclusion

I was able to find number if unrestricted quadruples but I am not able to figure out how can we find the remaining conditions to reach the final solution. Also I came to know this question can be done using DFS .

How can we do this question with  Inclusion Exclusion/ DFS

Comment: `such that Li ≤ Xi ≤ Ri for i = 1, 2, 3, 4` what's Li,Ri?

Comment: Please clarify what you are looking for. For example, why is 1 2 1 3 not an output.

Comment: @gnasher729 Input is L1=1, R1=4, ..., L4=4, R4=4, so 3 cannot appear in the fourth position. Only numbers satisfying 4 <= x4 <= 4 can appear in the fourth position, i.e., x4=4 always.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It looks like it is homework or comes from a competitive programming site. You should provide a link if possible.

Comment: If you don't provide the source, then it looks like an attempt to get credit for a competition problem you can't solve, while trying to make it hard for the people who can solve the problem to get credit. If you are not claiming to have created the problem, give the source.

Comment: @DouglasZare I appreciate your consent  but I believe you should be little patient when expecting a reply. I was having network issue for past one hour. And I read this question on Quora.[Here](  https://www.quora.com/Given-Li-and-Ri-for-i-1-2-3-4-Find-the-number-of-4-tuples-X1-X2-X3-X4-of-integers-such-that-Li-Xi-Ri-and-Xi-Xi+1-for-each-i-Input-1-4-1-3-1-2-4-4-output-8-1-2-1-4-1-3-1-4-1-3-2-4-2-1-2-4-2-3-1-4-2-3-2-4-3-1-2-4-3-2-1-4-Please-help-How-can-we-solve-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclusion/Exclusion will give you the number of quadruples, but won't give you the quadruples themselves.

Let Ai be the set of quadruples satisfying Lj<=Xj<=Rj for all j, with Xi=X(i+1) (where the indices are cyclic, so X5 means X1). In the example you provided,

```
A1 = { (1114), (1124), (2214), (2224), (3314), (3324) }
A2 = { (1114), (2114), (3114), (4114), (1224), (2224), (3224), (4224) }
A3 = { } (empty set)
A4 = { (4114), (4214), (4314), (4124), (4224), (4324) }
```

We also need the intersections of pairs of sets:

```
A1 cap A2 = { (1114), (2224) } (note first three numbers identical)
A1 cap A3 = { }
A1 cap A4 = { } (can't have X4=X1=X2)
A2 cap A3 = { }
A2 cap A4 = { (4114), (4224) }
A3 cap A4 = { }
```

Intersections of triples of sets:

```
A1 cap A2 cap A3 = { }
A1 cap A2 cap A4 = { }
A1 cap A3 cap A4 = { }
A2 cap A3 cap A4 = { }
```

And the intersection of all the sets:

```
A1 cap A2 cap A3 cap A4 = { }
```

[Inclusion/exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) in its complementary form tells us that

```
|intersection of complements of Ai| = |unrestricted quadruples| 
- sum of |Ai| + sum of |Ai cap Aj| - sum of |Ai cap Aj cap Ak| 
+ sum of |Ai cap Aj cap Ak cap Al|
```

where none of the indices i,j,k,l are equal. In your example,

```
|intersection of complements of Ai| = 4x3x2x1 - (6+8+0+6) + (2+0+0+0+2+0) - (0+0+0+0) + 0 
= 24 - 20 + 4 - 0 + 0 = 8
```

In order to find the |Ai| and their intersections, you have to find intersections of intervals [Li,Ri] and multiply the lengths of intersections by the lengths of unrestricted intervals. For example,

```
|A1| = |[1234] cap [123]| x |[12]| x |[4]| = 3 x 2 x 1 = 6
|A2 cap A4| = |[123] cap [12]| x |[4] cap [1234]| = |[12]| x |[4]| = 2 x 1 = 2
```

I don't see what depth first search has to do with it in this approach.

Comment: Its good . but how have you found A1,A2,A3...and how A3=empty set... After that its all theory of the principle so its quiet clear..

Comment: can't we have x3=x4 for A3..?

Comment: No x3 is 1 or 2 and x4 is 4 so you can't have x3=x4. I show an example of finding A1 and A2 cap A4 in the last shaded box.

Comment: Superb...Got it...can you provide an algo for your approach? It seems O(1) algo for each test case if we write direct formula...

Comment: I think it's O(1) if programmed properly. No loops are required. As you suggest, just write a formula for each component of inclusion/exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if the sets are disjoint or share elements. For n = 4, meaning quadruples, as you asked about, I think I got it down to between 1 and 4 iterations if we commit the ends to four types describing if `x_1` is a member of `X2` and `x_4` a member of `X3`.

Example with three iterations:

```
input = {1,2,3}{1,2}{1,2,3}{3,4}

2 * (1)(12)(123)(3) = (1)(2)(1)(3) = 2 * 1          // x_1 ∈ X2, x_4 ∈ X3
2 * (1)(12)(123)(4) = (1)(2)(13)(4) = 2 * 2          // x_1 ∈ X2, x_4 ∉ X3
1 * (3)(12)(123)(4) = (3)(12)(12,3)(4) = 1 * (2 + 2)  // x_1 ∉ X2, x_4 ∉ X3
Total = 10
```

Example with one iteration:

```
input = {1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,4}{1,2,3,4}          // x_1 ∈ X2, x_4 ∈ X3

12 * (1)(1234)(1234)(2) = (1)(2,34)(134)(2) = 12 * (3 + 4)
Total = 84
```

Comment: i am unable to understand your point. If you can elaborate a little more it may give some insight. thanks

Comment: @Ashish each parenthesis contains the options for digits `Xi`, from left to right. For the first two groups of (1,2,3) we have 3 items to choose 2 from, hence `C(3,2)` but can arrange them as we like, hence `permutations of C(3,2)`. If they end in 3, we have two choices for the next group. If they end in 1 or 2, we have only one choice for the next group.

Comment: @Ashish `4 (anything ) 4 =0` because X4 ≠ X1

Comment: ברק  let say we have 1 3 ,
1 2 ,
1 3,
3 4,
  o/p=
10 .. How will you do for this

Comment: what does "o/p= 10" mean?